# Divide and Conquer Algorithm Max Number in Array

Tags: java, arrays, max, divide-and-conquer

I'm new to divide and conquer algorithms and need to construct one to find the largest number in an array. Below is my code, I understand I need to divide the array into 2 parts, then recursively find the maximum in each part. Then, combine and find the largest in the 2 parts. Below is my code, I'm struggling to figure out how to recursively call the function to find the maximum in each part.

```
private static int problem(int[] histogram) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = histogram.length -1;
        if (left == right){
            return left;
        }
        int middle = (left + right)/2;

        return -1;
    }
```

Also, would this be O(n log n) time complexity?

Answer (score 2):

```java
static int maxNumber(int[] array) {
        switch (array.length) {
            case 1:
              return array[0];
            case 2:
              return array[0] > array[1]
                ? array[0]
                : array[1];
            default:
              int left = maxNumber(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, (int) (array.length / 2)));
              int right = maxNumber(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, (int) (array.length / 2), array.length));
              return left > right
                ? left
                : right;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, in recursions the most important part is handling the end conditions. Telling the recursion when to stop. In our case, we stop when we have one or two numbers in an array (if we devide array with 3 elements we get one with 2 and one with 1).

After you handle the end conditions, what's left is the recursion. You divide the array into two parts and run the same function on each part. This will give you (eventually) the answer.

Bear in mind that the space complexity of such a solution is quite high. You create two sub-arrays each time you call the recursive functions. This could be solved with a method signature of sorts: `maxNumber(array, start, end)` which will be first called as `maxNumber(array, 0, array.length)` and each recursive run, instead of copying the array, you just call the method with the same array reference, but you narrow the `start` and `end` pointers.